# Initialize multiple jQuery sliders programatically, each with a different onChange function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll try and keep this straightforward. I am using jQuery sliders and trying to initialize them all at once using an array:

```
sliders.push(new slider('paletteControl','pSlider',0,255,100,sliderChange()));

function slider (context, id, min, max, defaultvalue, changeFunc) {
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.defaultvalue = defaultvalue;
    this.changeFunc = changeFunc;
```

}

Where context is the ID of its intended parent div and changeFunc is the function I want it to call on change.

My Init function loops through this array and appends the markup according to the context, and then tries to init each jquery slider like so:

```
$(id).slider({
      range: "min",     
      min: sliders[i].min,   
      max: sliders[i].max,
      value: sliders[i].defaultvalue,
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      change: function() {
          sliders[i].changeFunc();
      }
 });
```

The min, max, and value inits work fine, presumably since they happen exactly once, during the init, but the change function fails pretty miserably, again presumably because it's simply trying to look up sliders[i] on each change (i being a long dead iterator by that point).

My question is - how can I programatically init a bunch of jquery sliders, each with a different onChange function? Without doing them manually, that is.

EDIT: Got some great help from Ramon de Paula Marques below, though in the end I had to do it a different way altogether because I was unable to pass a value to the function. What I ended up doing, for better or worse, was creating a wrapper function that simply looked up the proper change function once called based on the id of the slider that called it.

```
function parcelSliderFunction(caller, value)
{
   for (var x = 0; x < sliders.length; x++)
    {
        if(sliders[x].id == caller) {
            sliders[x].callback(value);
            return;
        }
    }

    console.log("id " + caller + " not found, you done screwed up.");
    return;

}
```

I should probably use a dictionary for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to remove parentheses of the function as parameter, in this line

```
sliders.push(new slider('paletteControl','pSlider',0,255,100,sliderChange()));
```

It becomes

```
sliders.push(new slider('paletteControl','pSlider',0,255,100,sliderChange));
```

Then you get the change function like this (without parentheses)

```
$(id).slider({
      range: "min",     
      min: sliders[i].min,   
      max: sliders[i].max,
      value: sliders[i].defaultvalue,
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      change: sliders[i].changeFunc
 });
```

OR

```
$(id).slider({
      range: "min",     
      min: sliders[i].min,   
      max: sliders[i].max,
      value: sliders[i].defaultvalue,
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      }
 });

$( id ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: This works great except I can't pass the current value of the slider for two reasons:

#1: trying to pass ANY value breaks this, which makes sense. The Change function for each slider fires immediately on load and then not again. 

#2. Even if #1 wasn't happening, attempting to pass the current slider value gives me a "you used a method before init" error on the slider.

Comment: You can get the current value with jquery inside the sliderChange function, you don't need to pass it as parameter. Try this: var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );

Comment: Understood - but the function doesn't necessarily know which slider called it. It's a pain, and maybe I'm just designing this wrong.

Comment: Well it should, in my mind your design was slider1 has sliderChange1 function, slider2 has sliderChange2 function...

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more clear on that - This app will have a couple dozen sliders that will target maybe 10 functions, so multiple sliders will use the same function.

Comment: You will have to remove that change: initialization and bind an event listener like this "$( ".selector" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {} );" let me edit my answer

Comment: I really appreciate your help - but I think the new method breaks because I can no longer look up the changeFunc in the array...possibly because it's looking for an 'i' iterator that is no longer valid?

Comment: yes you are right, you cannot use that "i" inside an inner function that is called by a callback function like that "change"

Comment: thanks for your help, I ended up just calling a single wrapper function every time that passes the id of the caller, looks up the correct function based on that id, and then passes the value. It's probably not too efficient, but it works for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may call the changeFunc using window[value.changeFunc] as shown below

```
function newSlider(context, id, min, max, defaultvalue, changeFunc) {
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.defaultvalue = defaultvalue;
    this.changeFunc = changeFunc;
}

function func1() {
    $('#output').append("func1<br>");
}

function func2() {
    $('#output').append("func2<br>");
}

function func3() {
    $('#output').append("func3<br>");
}

var sliders = [];
sliders.push(new newSlider('paletteControl', 'pSlider1', 0, 255, 100, "func1"));
sliders.push(new newSlider('paletteControl', 'pSlider2', 0, 255, 200, "func2"));
sliders.push(new newSlider('paletteControl', 'pSlider3', 0, 255, 70, "func3"));

$.each(sliders, function(index, value) {
    $("#" + value.id).slider({
        range: "min",
        min: value.min,
        max: value.max,
        value: value.defaultvalue,
        change: window[value.changeFunc]
    });
});
```

Working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/nwjOrnwoI7NU3MY8jXYl?p=preview